# Compactness Theorem (Propositional Logic) and Compactness (Metric spaces).

Tags: general-topology, logic, metric-spaces, compactness, propositional-calculus

> **Definition.**
>
> A subset $E$ of a metric space $(X,\tau)$ is compact if every open cover of $E$ has a finite subcover.

> **Theorem (Compactness Theorem).**
>
> A set $\Gamma$ of formulas is satisfiable if and only if every finite subset $\hat \Gamma\subseteq \Gamma$ is satisfiable.

I've recently began studying metric spaces, and I remembered about the compactness theorem for propositional logic, so I wanted to know what's the connnection between it and the notion of compactness.

Could someone explain this in rather simple terms?

Comment: Here, you have the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842/why-is-compactness-in-logic-called-compactness